# Bounce or fade In texts and divs when shown on the screen React

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, wow.js

The part of the animation is very easy I can do it the thing is that I want to animate them when they are shown on the screen and without using pixels and offsets when to be responsive like on the phone mode also etc... And without changing my layouts because my pages are too messy
Please help I tried WOW js and animate.css they are working with pixels :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install react-animate-on-scroll`
And you can use animate.css animations on scroll that's perfect